# Android - Access to Fragment Components through Activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, fragment

I have a simple question which won't require for me to show any coding of mine. I have 1 Fragment Activity activity and 3 Fragments which are tabs. Those tabs have components such as ImageView, TextView etc.

Is there any way to access these components from Fragment Activity? I have to use them in there and assign their images etc. from the Fragment Activity.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should load the fragment in the activity by this way:

```
MyFragment fragment = new MyFragment();
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

and in **MyFragment** you should implement a method who return the data you need, like this:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
    ...
    TextView mTextView;
    ImageView mImageView;
    ...

    public ImageView getImageView() {
        return mImageView;
    }

    public TextView getTextView() {
        return mTextView;
    }

    ...
}
```

and in your activity call the methods like this:

```
 TextView fragmentTextView = fragment.getTextView();
 ImageView fragmentImageView = fragment.getImageView();
```

Comment: I've created the variables as you suggested "Tab1 tab1 = new Tab1();" which is My Fragment but I can not use Fragment Transaction it wants me to change Tab1 tab1 to Fragment tab1 (And yes, I've extended fragment on Tab1)

Comment: If It's a tab doesn't matter, the important it's the reference, you can put tab1.getImageView()